# Creating infinite circles inside of each other in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to create some trippy "animation" such as this image; [Trippy circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iAMl.jpg)

I can just place another circle into the circle by brute-forcing it. However, I am pretty sure that there is an easier way of doing it by either using "while" or "for". I am pretty new to coding so I have no idea which logic to use.

Here is my brute-forced code below.

```
int m = millis();

void setup(){
  
 size(1136,936);
 
}

void draw(){
  

  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  frameRate(1.3);
  background(255);
  
  
 if (millis() > m + 1000){
  for (int diameter = 0; diameter < 500; diameter = diameter+1) {
  float r1 = random(1,1000);
  float r2 = random(1,900);
  fill(255);
  circle(r1, r2, diameter);
  fill(0);
  circle(r1,r2,diameter/2);

}
 
}

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This comes close to what your example looks like (based on your original code):

```
int m = millis();

void setup(){
 size(1136,936);
}

int colors[] = { 0, 255 };

void draw(){
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  //frameRate(1.3);
  background(255);

   if (millis() > m + 1000) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i = i+1) {
      float x = random(1,1000);
      float y = random(1,900);
      float radius = 300;
      float delta = 30;
      
      int counter = 0;
      while (radius >= delta) {
        fill(colors[counter % colors.length]);
        ellipse(x, y, radius, radius);
        counter++;
        radius -= delta;
      }
    }
  }
}
```